# Converting String Query to Excuteable statement

Tags: typescript

if i have a query like this :

`row.Average < 99 && row.Department === \"lfs\" && row.Fail === 1`

provided as String ... how to convert it to executable code to use in if statement

ex:

```
if (row.Average < 99 && row.Department === \"lfs\" && row.Fail === 1){ /*doSomething*/ }
```

using Typescript .. i want algorithm to do that .. if there is no other ways

i have tried using eval() but iam getting forbidden eval

and also tried doing :

```
const Query = "row.Average < 99 && row.Department === \"lfs\" && row.Fail === 1";
const func = new Function("return " + Query + ";");
if (func()) {
   // code
}
```

and code just stops at if line .. and exit

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can just use the `eval` function to evaluate JavaScript expressions in TypeScript:

```js
const query = "row.Average < 99 && row.Department === \"lfs\" && row.Fail === 1";

const row = {Average: 98, Department: "lfs", Fail: 1}
console.log('query evaluates to ', eval(query));
if (eval(query)) {
    console.log('It was true')
} else {
    console.log('It was false')
}
```